# T-SQL: AVG function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

Can you please help me to find an AVG of my dataset for 'Count_of_Attno'?

AttNo as 'Count_of_Attno' is nvarchar.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), ArrDateTime, 120) as [Date],
       count(AttNo) as Count_of_Attno
FROM [dbo].[Main]
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), ArrDateTime, 120)
Order by CONVERT(CHAR(10), ArrDateTime, 120) desc
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to get the average without a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(AttNo) / COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(CHAR(10), ArrDateTime, 120)) as avg_count
FROM [dbo].[Main];
```